# Tag suggestion: international

Tags: discussion, tags

This tag should be used in question related with international careers, international opportunities, multicultural environments, etc.

Suggestion based in [*International Careers*](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53270/international-careers) proposal by Aladdin Mannai at Area51.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like we already have a [international](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international) tag, but only four questions have this tag.

There may be more questions here that could benefit from having this tag applied to them.  Anyone with 200 reputation or higher on this site can retag questions, but first, it may be a good idea for us to look at the four questions that bear this tag and ask what it means.

Looking at the questions, the main thing they all have in common is that the asker mentions at least two countries. For instance, one question is about language barriers, while others are about how to find jobs.  Looking deeper, the topics are actually much different, which makes me think that international could be too broad.

I suspect we'd need more information about what other kinds of questions have an international aspect to them before deciding on a tag. It could be better to split it up into more tags depending on the depth of the questions.

I don't think [international](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international) is necessarily a bad tag, and it could be helpful to add it to other questions, but I suspect there could also be other tags that could apply to these questions as well that would make it easier for people to find information and narrow the scope.

Comment: The only "problem" I can see is people using "international" to mean anything outside of their cultural context. For instance, "What is appropriate business greeting etiquette in France?" may be tagged as International, when it's really a domestic issue from a country different of the one of the asker. And that shouldn't be a precondition, should it?

Comment: @jmac - I believe what you just described is a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), and you're right, we should avoid them. It's probably best to retag international as something a little more targeted for those 4 questions now while it's still manageable. :)

Comment: I think that country or "continent" tags are a non-meta application of the same and could narrow things down (even though nobody may use the "Togo" tag over the next 3 years). Or subcontinents. Or whatever. Location is good, meta is bad.